# R numeric and categorical variables in multiple linear regression

Tags: r, integer, linear-regression, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I have a data frame that looks similar to this:

```
BMI<-c(13.4,14,15.6,16,13.4,12.9,17.7,18.3,17,16.5)
sport<-c(1,2,2,3,2,1,1,3,1,2)
social<-c("low","middle","middle","low","high","low","middle","middle","high","middle")
smoker<-c(1,0,0,1,2,3,2,2,2,1)

status<-c("low","high","low","middle","low","middle","middle","middle","high","low")
social<-as.factor(social)
status<-as.factor(status)
sport<-as.integer(sport)
smoker<-as.integer(smoker)

df<-data.frame(BMI,sport,social,status,smoker)
```

I want to perform a **multiple linear regression** on the variable **"BMI"** but I don´t know how to deal with the categorical variables or let´s say with the different formats in general.

How would I need to transform these variables to be able to get a meaningful result?

Comment: Hi there, you could try to do a generalized linear model using `?glm` and set your interactions in the `glm` call. For instance `glm(df,BMI~sport+social....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a generalized linear model and set categorical variables using `factor` like:

```
glm(data=iris,formula=Sepal.Width~Sepal.Length+Petal.Length+factor(Species))
```

Using your data:

```
glm(data=df,BMI~sport+social+status+smoker,family="gaussian")
```

If you want a linear model:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1<-df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character,as.factor)
lm(BMI~sport+social+status+smoker,data=df1)
```

Comment: Info on families: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94852/glm-gaussian-vs-glm-binomial-vs-log-link-glm-gaussian

Comment: would it make sense to transform the other variables to  factors as well, so that every variable has the same format and use linear regression instead of generalized linear regression?

Comment: I think it depends on the nature of the investigation and data. For this data it appears to make sense for all to be factors given say smoker is binary.

Comment: In my data smoker is not binary - the numbers stand for the amount of smokers in the household. The other variables are similiar. All variables are categories with at least three levels - only the BMI is a continious number.

Comment: To be honest that seems more to do with the stats. Perhaps take a look at this discusision: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267121/regression-for-categorical-independent-variables-and-a-continuous-dependent-one